# Use variables in batch to perform a command with varying inputs

Tags: variables, batch-file, command, system

How do I make a variable work in a batch command?

I want to do the following:

```
@echo off  
set /p Name=Choose your name:  
set /p PW=Choose your password:  
Net user %Name% %PW% /add
```

I just get "System Error 5"

Comment: "System Error 5" means "access denied". You need to do it with adminstrator privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Right-click on program icon (file.batch).
 Choose Run As Administrator.
```

[image]

```
 If you see a User Account Control prompt, accept it.
```

Comment: OH! i didn´t think of this... is it possible to do something like: cd (anyfolder) and Runasadmin.bat /Admin...? i mean opening it as admin with a CMD command..

Answer (score 0):

Run It As Administrator
and it will work